# Python-like unpacking list in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

For example in Python I can do something like:

```
li = [('John', 20, '360 244 4210'), ('Bill', 22, '360 244 4211'), ('Susan', 19, '360 244 4214')]
for name, age, phone_num in li:
    register(name, age)
    make_a_call(name, phone_num)
```

But in Groovy I have to do it like:

```
li = [['John', 20, '360 244 4210'], ['Bill', 22, '360 244 4211'], ['Susan', 19, '360 244 4214']]
li.each {
    name = it[0]
    age = it[1]
    phone = it[2]

    register(name, age)
    make_a_call(name, phone_num)
}
```

Is there any way in Groovy can I use to unpack list like Python?

Answer (score 5):

Groovy supports positional destructuring on closure arguments.  This
works for ordered collections (e.g. List or Tuple).

```
def list = [['John', 20, '360 244 4210'], ['Bill', 22, '360 244 4211'], ['Susan', 19, '360 244 4214']]
list.each { name, age, phone ->
    println([name, age, phone])
}
// → [John, 20, 360 244 4210]
// → [Bill, 22, 360 244 4211]
// → [Susan, 19, 360 244 4214]
```

Comment: This inconsistently doesn't work for me. I often get `No signature of method: XXX.doCall() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.Object;) values: [[2022.0, 4.0, 1]]` even though doing the following works fine:
`list.each { x -> def (int year, int month, int count) = x }`

Comment: @NathanCrause `[Ljava....` looks like an array of object. At least an array works with Groovy 4 in general. Hard to tell, what is going on, without a reproducible example.